# What is the "average relative humidity" of the Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, humidity

What is the current ratio of the amount of water in the Earth's atmosphere compared to its moisture storage capacity?

I see values like "a half" or "70% on various web pages, but can't find an actual source.  I can find good sources for trends and annual variations in the humidity, but they only give the percentage changes, such as these [UK Met Office trends](https://climate.metoffice.cloud/humidity.html).  The total water content of the atmosphere is also given in lots of places as [12,900 cubic kilometres](https://www.usgs.gov/special-topics/water-science-school/science/atmosphere-and-water-cycle), but I haven't found a corresponding water storage capacity integrated over the whole atmosphere.